# Android Studio build error (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm using the React Native v0.61.5 project and trying to build the app in Android Studio Hedgehog, but every time I get the following error, related questions and their answers didn't help to fix this, please take a look, any help is really appreciated:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
```